# Set minimum size of center pane in dojo BorderContainer

Tags: dojo

I am using BorderContainer for layout with center and bottom regions. I can set the minSize of bottom but I am not able to set a minimum size for the center region. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53a69ej7/

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
     data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true"
     id="borderContainer"
     style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center', minSize:100"
         style=" background: #990;">Hi, I'm center pane
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'bottom', minSize:100"
         style="background: #099;height:50%">Hi, I'm bottom pane
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set the minimum height of the center pane to be 100px so that when I drag the splitter up it does not go all the way up. Note that if you drag the splitter down, the height of the bottom region does not go below the specified minSize as expected.